# Trigger <input type="file"> file select with angular programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-img-crop

Im using ngImgCrop as can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexk111/rw6q9/).
What I try to achieve is that the image selection box will open automatically when i show(using ng-if) the:

```
<div ng-if="showImageSelector">
 <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
 <div class="cropArea">
  <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
 </div>
</div>
```

that is: i want to programatically open the image selection window, without even showing the user the:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

Iv'e tried put in the controller several variations of click event of the input, but none of them worked, so far iv'e tried:
1.

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#fileInput').triggerHandler('click');
  }, 0);
```

2.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.element('#fileInput').triggerHandler('click');
  });
```

3.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    angular.element('#fileInput').triggerHandler('click');
  }, 1000);
```

4.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up wrapping the ngImgCrop with my directive, in it iv'e placed that:

```
$timeout(function () {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).click();
      $log.debug("poped it");
    }, 250);
```

in the link function.
Aside the real element i show for the img selector, iv'e placed this at my index.html:

```
<div ng-show="false">
  <my-image-select cropped-image="groupDetails.newPic" return-func="groupDetails.imageSelectFinish"></my-image-select>
</div>
```

and it works.
without the extra invisible my-image-select in index.html, the file chooser only auto open from the second attempt.

Answer (score 1):

For trigger the file selector open programmatically, the answer is yes.

**But you need to make sure this event was fired by THE USER.**

For example, you have a button there, you attach the click event on it. **After the user click this button**, inside the event handler, you can trigger by javascript code e.g,`document.getElementById('fileInput').click()`. This should work.

However, if you want to simply run several lines of javascript code to open a file selector **without user's click**, that's not possible, because that violate the security policy.

So I [added some code to your sample](https://jsfiddle.net/rw6q9/3066/),

html,

```
<button ng-click='open()'>Open selector</button>
```

javascript,

```
$scope.open = function() {
     document.getElementById('fileInput').click(); //this work
};
```

Hope this would solve your problem. : )